# О семантике личных и безличных предложений

Tags: предикатив, грамматическая-основа

Вот текст:

*Что с ним? Он и сам не понимал. **У него было чувство** необъяснимого страха, но **ему** действительно **было страшно**.*

Здесь описано **состояние субъекта** в определенный **момент** прошедшего времени. Но в первой части **двусоставное** предложение (чувство было), а во второй части **односоставное безличное** (было страшно).

Почему предложения со сходной **семантикой** имеют разную **грамматику?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Другими словами, почему в предложениях нет подлежащего?

```
У него было страшно
Ему было страшно
```

Правильный вопрос, я тоже такой формулировал здесь, когда начинал знакомиться с грамматикой. Наверняка, по нему есть хорошая аргументация в АГ-1980. А я пока дам свою аргументацию. Вот я специально понакидал схожих предложений:

```
В комнате все было разбросано // личное
В комнате было разбросано // безличное
Мне было все равно // безличное
Мне было все пофиг //личное
У меня было страшно // безличное
У меня был ужас // личное
```

На мой взгляд основная причина одна. Наречия отвечающие на вопрос **как** не могут быть подлежащим, в отличии от наречий отвечающих на вопрос **что**:

```
Настало послезавтра (что?) // но не как???
У меня было страшно (как?) // но не что????
У меня был ужас (что?)
```

Я потом дополню ответ.

PS что еще можно предъявить синтаксису насчет подлежащих и безличных, так это разницу в негативных и позитивных вариантах. Что-то типа

```
снега было по колено // личное
вообще не было снега // безличное
```

Во! Нашел [статью](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2), в которой некоторые предикативы считают подлежащими

> 4.5 Вопрос о подлежащем предикатива В большинстве работ, относящихся к русской грамматической традиции, предложения с предикативами
> считаются безличными (см. в том числе [Грамматика 1954] и [Грамматика
> 1980]). При этом безличные предложения понимаются как односоставные,
> не имеющие никакого подлежащего (это понимание принято и в статье
> Безличность), а не только личного или именного подлежащего. Тем самым
> считается, что все конструкции с предикативами не имеют подлежащего,
> сентенциальные актанты предикативов (инфинитивный оборот или оборот с
> союзом что или чтобы) в этой традиции не считаются подлежащими.
>
> В данной статье синтаксическую структуру предложений с предикативами
> предлагается рассматривать отдельно для случаев, когда в предложении
> нет сентенциального актанта (п.4.5.1), и для случаев, когда такой
> актант есть (п.4.5.2). Предложения второго типа мы тестируем на
> наличие подлежащего – проверяем, не является ли подлежащим
> сентенциальный актант (см. критерии, предложенные в п.4.5.2).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Надо почитать и подумать)

Answer (score 0):

Чем **трудна эта тема**, ведь пользователи часто ошибаются и считают двусоставное предложение односоставным безличным?

1. Здесь **сходная семантика**, а грамматические **формы** разные, то есть имеет место синтаксическая **синонимия.**

*Он боится. Он испытывает чувство страха.  У него **было чувство** страха.*  Это **двусоставные** предложения.

*Ему **было страшно**.* Безличное предложение (предикативное наречие).

*У него **не было** чувства страха*. Безличное предложение при отрицании.

2. Кажется, что **разная семантика** у таких предложений.

*У него **было чувство** страха* (в текущий момент). *У него **было хорошее чувство** юмора* (вообще).

Но по словарю можно увидеть **два** значения у ***быть***: (1) **существовать** (в текущий момент); (2) **иметься  наличии** (вообще).